# What attacks (and associated controller movements) are effective against Dark Link?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time, zelda-ocarina-of-time-3d

In OoT, the mini-boss in the Water Temple is Dark Link, and he functions very much as a mirror image of the player. Almost all moves by Link (the player) are parried, and even countered (I.e. the stab is countered by him landing on your sword!)

He is easily overcome by the use of the Biggoron Sword, and the Megaton Hammer, but is he beatable with the Master Sword?

Which moves/tactics are effective against Dark Link when using the Master Sword?

Comment: Try spinning, that's a neat trick.

Comment: The [Dark Link](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Link_(Ocarina_of_Time)#Battle) implies that it is possible, but I personally have never see it done. I'm not going to post an answer as the information in the wiki - while useful(?) - is very vague as far as how to perform the strategy